# Trouble installing OpenJDK 12 into Eclipse 2019-12

Tags: java, eclipse, java-12, eclipse-2019-12

I have a new laptop and installed Eclipse 2019-12.  I also downloaded OpenJDK12 (12.0.1) because I have a project which needs that version.  I have unzipped the jdk into C:\Program Files\java\jdk-12.0.1.  When I try to add the version to Eclipse, though, I get the following error:
**Target is not a JDK Root.  Java executable was not found**

[image]

I can't install the Java 12 2019-03 support patch because it tells me that it's not compatible with my version.  Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: Re download a fresh copy of jdk12. I had similar problem with jdk13 and re downloading fresh copy worked. Do remember to add a jre folder inside you eclipse because eclipse search for bin there.

Comment: Eclipse usually looks for `java.exe` in the `bin` folder. Is it present? Unzipping instead of installing may mess with the file access conditions as well, if you install it as a different user. I'd prefer an executable installer.

Answer (score 0):

[Sample JDK image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQXSY.png)

Go to Eclipse > Preference > select Java > click on "Installed JREs"  > Browse in JRE Home directory > select the JDK folder before bin directory > Finish

FYI: Attached a sample JDK

Reinstall the JDK 12 if still not working